# Does the Grappled Condition limit multiple Natural Attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

How many attacks does an Eidolon with 4 natural claw-like attacks get when they have the grappled condition due to being grappled?

> Grappled creatures cannot move and take a –4 penalty to Dexterity. A grappled creature takes a –2 penalty on all attack rolls and combat maneuver checks, except those made to grapple or escape a grapple. **In addition, grappled creatures can take no action that requires two hands to perform.**

Comment: Did the eidolon grapple its foe or did the foe grapple the eidolon?

Comment: I believe both obtain the grappled condition, but in this scenario the eidolon was being grappled

Comment: That actually makes **all the difference** and should be included as part of the question (or mention that you want answers for both circumstances).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With some restrictions, the grappled creature can make a full attack

In the description of the combat maneuver [Grapple](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Grapple), the section If You Are Grappled says that

> Instead of attempting to break or reverse the grapple, **you can** take any action that doesn’t require two hands to perform, such as cast a spell or **make a**n attack or **full attack with a light or one-handed weapon against** any creature within your reach, including **the creature that is grappling you**.

[Natural weapons are considered light weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-finesse-combat---final). The eidolon suffers a −2 penalty on attack rolls with each natural weapon attack due to the condition [grappled](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Grappled), but as claws are [primary natural attacks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Natural-Attacks), it should suffer no additional penalties.

The grappled eidolon *isn't* taking an action to try to use its claws to employ bolt cutters, tie its shoes, or play guitar, and, instead, taking an action to use its claws to just rip up some fool grappling it. That's not a two-handed-or-more task but a task for each individual claw.

Comment: Which rule book edition are you referencing?

Comment: Ahh okay, I have two editions, the 6th 2013 is the more recent. I was reading my 2009 that says "Instead of attempting to
break or reverse the grapple, you can take any action that
requires only one hand to perform" by mistake

Comment: Does this mean that a character dual wielding short swords may also make a full round attack with both weapons while being grappled?

Comment: Yes, but not if they are the one doing the grappling, you really need to update the Q.