# Full attacking with natural while grappling or being grappled

Tags: pathfinder-1e, grapple, natural-weapon

My GM said that a creature with several appenges can full attack with all of their natural attacks towards me?

I know that the grapple rules specify *"Instead of attempting to break or reverse the grapple, you can take any action that doesn’t require two hands to perform, such as cast a spell or make an attack or full attack with a light or one-handed weapon against any creature within your reach, including the creature that is grappling you"*
I'm reading the a light weapon meaning it's a single light weapon and not all, such as a dagger, is this incorrect?

p.s. Are hands and appendeges in any way connected or are the grappling rules completely broken while you're using anything other than hands, say tentacles etc

My GM is a stickler for rules, so any answers with sources is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Closely related.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/61802/8610)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Full Attacking is a viable option when Grappled

You are only restricted from using actions that explicitly require two hands at once (such as using a two-handed weapon) while grappled. I would personally rule that this rules out Two-Weapon fighting as well, although by RAW it would be functional. You can make any number of [Natural Weapon attacks](https://www.aonprd.com/UMR.aspx?ItemName=Natural%20Attacks) as part of a Full Attack, albeit as Secondary Natural Attacks if the creature is also wielding a manufactured weapon.

> Creatures with natural attacks and attacks made with weapons can use both as part of a full attack action (although a creature must forgo one natural attack, be it a claw, slam, or tentacle attack, for each weapon clutched in a limb that would otherwise make a natural attack). Such creatures attack with their weapons normally but treat all of their natural attacks as secondary attacks during that attack, regardless of their type.

Natural Attacks (which is as close as we get to for 'appendages' as a game-term) cannot 'wield weapons', but the limb that they are on might be able to, in which case it counts as a 'hand' in the weapon rules.

Comment: As an aside, my group has historically ignored the restriction against using two-handed weapons (or TWF) when grappled. I don't necessarily recommend it, but not much changes; most parties are far more likely to be grappled than grapple something, and in those cases, the party Barbarian and two-handed Fighter are happy because they get to have more fun.

Comment: Pro tip: grapple builds are bad, and trying to grapple without building for it is also bad.

Comment: That's generally accurate. It's difficult to do anything other than low damage, and only control (usually) one creature at a time; also, fights tend to be pretty one-sided in practice (one side has a clear advantage, and there's not much the other side can do about it) so you either shut down the enemy (not fun for the GM) or accomplish nothing (not fun for you). The best ones are the ones that do other stuff but can 'turn on' grappling when appropriate or get it as a side-benefit (Brawlers, some Animal Companions).

Comment: Not to mention how few options there are to get around the 4th level spell Freedom of Movement